# Suppose you have given two identical materials one is a metal and another is semiconductor? How will you distinguish between them?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, metals

Suppose you have given two identical materials one is a metal and another is semiconductor? How will you distinguish between them?

Comment: If the materials were _identical,_ then it would be impossible to tell the difference between them. There wouldn't be any difference. That's what "identical" means. You probably meant that the two sample were similar _in certain ways_ (e.g., same color, same texture, same density,...)

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to word it as "given an unknown material, metallic in appearance, how do you tell whether it is a metal or semiconductor"?

Answer (score 4):

With a fixed voltage, measure the resistance (using Ohm's law) as a function of temperature. Most metals' resistance increases with temperature, while semiconductors' generally decrease.

Note that it is a bit oxymoronic to say "identical materials" when one is a metal and one is a semiconductor. Maybe you meant "you cannot see any obvious difference"?